# Favouriting a question then leaving it quickly crashes the Android app

Tags: bug, android-app, bookmarks

When you favourite a question, this little flydown notification appears saying "Post favorited":

> [image: "post favorited"]

(I don't know if it's actually called a flydown, but stick with me.)

The same kind of notification appears when you unfavourite a question.

Here's how to crash the app:

1. Visit a question.
2. Favourite it.
3. Hit Back to leave the question *before* that flydown notification appears. If you've got a little bit of network latency, that will give you a better opportunity to do it.
4. Wait for the crash! It'll happen *around the time* that notification should have appeared, I think.

This isn't a problem with other notifications. For example, if I try to remove my upvote on that question then hit back, the error saying I can't remove my upvote will still appear even though I'm now on the questions list.

This occurs in app version <s>1.0.51</s> 1.0.77 on a HTC One running Android 4.4.3.

Comment: This is an awesome catch. On it!

Comment: How to favorite a question in android app?

Comment: @CRags it's in the context menu for a question. Tap the bit below the question itself where it says when it was asked or last edited, with three dots beside it.

Comment: Thanks @doppelgreener